# How to save App Data to reload it when app starts next time? WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Let's say there's a Textbox in my app and I'm getting the username from the Textbox. I'm saving the username to a string. But when I relaunch the app, the string will be null. How can I save user data so that I will get it next time my app starts?

I know File reading & writing methods but I'm looking for a way that will not involve file reading & writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use project settings ([Settings Page, Project Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ApplicationSetting);k(Designer_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsDesigner);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)&rd=true)). Once a setting is created you can set from the GUI like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.FirstUserSetting = "abc";
```

When you close the main form (there is an event for this) you can persist all settings like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Ultimately a file in the user's profile is used to store the data, but you don't have to deal with it directly.

If you need to save a list of, for example strings, you can do this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] someList = Properties.Settings.Default.myList.Split('|');
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(someList);
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    string[] someList = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        someList[i] = (string)listBox1.Items[i];
    }
    Properties.Settings.Default.myList = string.Join("|", someList);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Ok so if I want to save a List<string>, how do I do it?

Comment: You mentioned a TextBox in you question. You can use string.Join to create a delimited string that you can then assign to a setting before saving the setting. When you load the form, you can string.Split the setting's value into an array and use the array to populate the List.

Comment: Can you please show the process with a code example?